# Unable to set custom breadcrumbs

Tags: breadcrumbs

I've enabled the Custom Breadcrumbs module and given the administator (me) rights to create custom breadcrumbs.
I am seeing this message on nodes, where it should allow me to set the custom breadcrumb:

Custom breadcrumbs have not been created for this test_content_type page. Use the Custom Breadcrumbs Administration Page to create a breadcrumb.

Going to this page the settings are as follows:
Show only custom_breadcrumbs where

```
Type is node
```

Where I see:
Namesort descending Breadcrumb Type Operations
No custom breadcrumbs have been defined.

What am I missing?

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation provided with the module, or at least not making it clear that you did so.

Answer (score 1):

From the custom breadbcrumbs [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/README.txt):

> - Enable the module
> - Assign 'administer custom breadcrumbs' permission to those roles that should   be allowed to add/edit/delete custom breadcrumbs.
> - Assign 'use php in custom breadcrumbs' to roles that should be allowed to use   php to determine breadcrumb visibility.
> - Go to Administer > Site building > Custom breadcrumbs to add new breadcrumbs
> - Click "Add a new custom breadcrumb"
> - Choose the node type to create a breadcrumb trail for
> - For the titles, put each "crumb" one line after another (There is no need to   put in "home"):
>
>   Item 1   SubItem A   SuperSubItem X
> - For the paths, put the path to each crumb starting after the domain name.   Don't include a leading or trailing slash.
>
>   item1   item-1/subitem-a   item-1/subitem-a/supersubitem-x
> - Click save to save the breadcrumb
> - Visit the page and your breadcrumb should appear!

Comment: Thank you.
I don't have the following:
Go to Administer > Site building > Custom breadcrumbs to add new breadcrumbs
Click "Add a new custom breadcrumb"

Also, Re: Choose the node type to create a breadcrumb trail for I've got the following:
Show only custom_breadcrumbs where

    Type is node
Is this correct?

Comment: This documentation is for Drupal 6.  If you are on Drupal 7, check the README file inside the module.  If the instructions provided with the module are incorrect or incomplete, file an issue in the module's issue queue on Drupal.org.  The instructions provided with modules should be correct; if not, it is a bug and needs to be reported on Drupal.org.

Comment: Because I am getting this message "Custom breadcrumbs have not been created for this test_content_type page." Does this mean I need to do something to the content type I would like to add breadcrumbs to??